# PHP update different fields on DB from one form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page on my site which is like an inbox.

I have checkboxes next to each message

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='$id'>
```

I then have 2 submit buttons

```
    <button class="btn btn-default" input type="submit" name="read_button" value="read"> 
<span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete Selected</button>

<button class="btn btn-default" input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="Delete"> 
<span class="fa fa-check"></span> Mark as Read</button>
```

My question, is how do I make the database do 2 different things depending on which submit button is clicked?

Example below for my delete query

```
   if (isset($_POST['delete_button')) {
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $check_list = $_POST['check_list'];
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE mail SET mail_deleted='1' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $check_list).")") or die(mysql_error());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the value : If value=="delete", then this query : XXX

Elseif value=="read" : do this : YYY

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to check if items were checked, first and, after that, choose the query depending on the button which was clicked. See the provided code for an example.

```
<form action="filename.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" name="read_button" value="Read">
</form>
```

Make sure to replace `filename.php` in that code. I made the HTML Markup as simple as possible.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
        $check_list = implode(",", $_POST['check_list']);
        if (isset($_POST['delete_button'])) $query = "UPDATE mail SET mail_deleted='1' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $check_list).")";
        if (isset($_POST['read_button']))   $query = "UPDATE mail SET mail_read='1' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $check_list).")";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
?>
```

However, you should note that the database extension you're using is deprecated. There are multiple alternatives, `mysqli` being the "easier" one (quite similiar to `mysql`) and PDO being the more object oriented solution. The support of prepared statements makes mysql queries easier and safer. See the official PHP website for more information : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Comment: Hi, when i click the Mark As Read button using this code it still deletes?

Comment: I don't know your exact database setup, but the "Delete" button removes the elements with the given IDs, while the "Read" button sets the "mail_deleted " flag to 1

Comment: It shouldnt actually delete, it should just mark the mail_deleted field to 1 for deleted and set the mail_read to 1 when mark as read clicked. at the moment both buttons are marking deleted as 1?

Comment: Then, both queries are nearly the same. Look at the edited answer to check if it fits. However, you might want to check out some tutorials / etc. about building queries if you're not sure.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated ,my code however it is still marking them as deleted when I click the read button?

Comment: No, it won't. Clicking on the read button will cause the according query to be used. That, for example, will set mail_read to 1. Only clicking on the delete button will Trigger the DELETE FROM... query. In this example, only one action can be executed at a time, not both. You should really learn the basics of PHP before trying to use SQL.

Comment: Ok, now no buttons do anything? I have the buttons as in my question and the PHP as in your answer?

Comment: The edited version is my final idea. If you add print($query); , it should Show you the selected query. It might be an error with your HTML Markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['delete_button'))
{
    // Do delete stuff
}
elseif (isset($_POST['read_button'))
{
    // Do read stuff
}
```

Side note 1: Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of legacy `mysql` functions

Side note 2: Use [placeholders](http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/understanding-placeholders-in-pdo/) instead of inserting the request values directly into the SQL string, as the latter opens up for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch`, since your button will bring the 'value'. First, rename your buttons with the same name, like:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" input type="submit" name="button" value="Delete"> <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete Selected</button>

<button class="btn btn-default" input type="submit" name="button" value="Read"> <span class="fa fa-ok"></span> Mark as Read</button>
```

And in your php, put the switch instead of `if`:

```
$check_list = $_POST['check_list'];
switch($_POST['button']){
    case "Delete":
        $result = "UPDATE mail SET mail_deleted='1' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $check_list).")";
    break;
    case "Read":
        $result = "UPDATE mail SET mail_read='1' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $check_list).")";
    break;
}
mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I have uised this code, however both buttons mark the mail as deleted?

Comment: This example is just to 'separate' the choices. You must define what you want to do with each one. I mean, it'll be deleted only if you define it in each case.

Comment: It shouldnt actually delete, it should just mark the mail_deleted field to 1 for deleted and set the mail_read to 1 when mark as read clicked. at the moment both buttons are marking deleted as 1?

Comment: No, as you stated, you just wanted a sample to divide the buttons return, so that's what it does. Now you have to put your queries into the cases. I updated my answer now, take a look.

Comment: Another thing, as soon as you can, replace *mysql_** functions for *mysqli_* or *PDO* ;)